# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'" loading data to Elastisearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to load data from PostgreSQL to Elasticsearch and I write below code, but it gives me the error in for loop, my code is as below:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

#res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
sql_conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="priyanka",user="postgres",password="admin")
sql_cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
sql=('SELECT * FROM "Sales"')
sql_cursor=sql_cursor.execute(sql)
tempList=[]
tmp = {}
for row in sql_cursor.fetchall():
    print("1")
    Sales_id =str(row[0])
    Product_name =str(row[1])
    sales =str(row[2])

    tmp["Sales_id"]=Sales_id
    tmp["name"]=Product_name
    tmp["sales"]=sales
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Priyanka Pagar/Softwares/Team/Python37/elastic - Copy.py", line 16, in <module>
    for row in sql_cursor.fetchall():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

Comment: Connecting as the `postgres` user from an application is poor practice. Your SELECT may have failed because you did not specify a schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
sql_cursor=sql_cursor.execute(sql)
```

to

```
sql_cursor.execute(sql)
```

Because the [`execute`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) method returns `none`, this re-assignment destroys the ability to later fetch the results from the cursor.